# JAXB error when unmarshalling Apache CXF SOAP response after upgrading from version 2.2.11 to 2.3.0+

Tags: soap, jaxb, cxf

After upgrading the following JAXB dependencies from 2.2.11 to anything > 2.3.0 the following error occurs when unmarshalling the response:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"MessageKey"). Expected elements are <{http://some.namespace}MessageKey>
```

As we can see the issue is that it seems to be unmarshalling with no name space.

If I update the WSDL to `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` it solves this error, but we don't want to modify the WSDL.

I've used SOAPUI to validate that the response indeed has a namespace, and when using JAXB <= 2.2.11, the namespace is unmarshalled correctly.

These are our dependencies:

```
<org-apache-cxf.version>3.5.0</org-apache-cxf.version>
<org-sun-jaxb.version>2.3.0</org-sun-jaxb.version>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
<version>${org-apache-cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
<version>${org-apache-cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
<version>${org-apache-cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
<version>${org-sun-jaxb.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
<version>${org-sun-jaxb.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

We've tried all sorts of combinations of dependencies and even upgrading them all to the latest version, the same error occurs. I've gone the route off attempting to do custom unmarshalling but there should be a simpler solution.

If anyone has any idea or some guidance in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it, we've spent a lot of time on this already.

Comment: This seems to be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106695/why-does-cxf-throw-an-unmarshalling-error-on-elements-that-have-no-namespace-pre

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that JAXB versions <= 2.2.11 are less strict when unmarshalling with namespaces.

the only appropriate solution for my problem is indeed setting `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` in the WSDL.

The generated classes are otherwise set with a **package level annotation** that strictly requires everything to be namespaced.

`@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.some.com/namespace/for/my/package", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)`

But because the response coming from the service was not namespacing at the property level, and unmarshalling expected it. I got the above error.